# Article use in "She is a/the of two children."

Tags: articles, definite-articles

I am confused by seeing the definite article in sentences like "She is *the* mother of *x*" where *x* has not been mentioned yet. For example, *"She lives in Pittsburgh and is the mother of two daughters and two stepdaughters."* and many other examples found by [this ngrams query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is%20a%20mother%20of%20two%2Cis%20the%20mother%20of%20two&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20a%20mother%20of%20two%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20the%20mother%20of%20two%3B%2Cc0).

Is the indefinite article acceptable here at all?

How is it different from *"She is a teacher?"* where we generally use the indefinite article? Is it a more general use case and how can I recognize it and avoid mistakes?

Comment: You won't be able to avoid mistakes using the wrong article. But anyway, by saying *the mother of two children* you are stating an *identifying characteristic* of who she is. You are mentioning part of her identity  (that she has two children) even if it is the first time you have mentioned her.

Comment: @user9825893y50932 I am not saying it isn't a duplicate because you must be much more knowledgeable. However could you point me to the specific point that covers my example?

Comment: BTW the other question is looking for *simple rules*, I would like an explanation of this specific pattern and the difference to "She is a teacher.". If it is explained in a duplicate, that will be perfect! But please point mo to the explanation.

Comment: Vladimir, what diference does it make if X has not been mentioned yet?

Comment: Well, "She is the mother of the naughty child we discussed." is kinda obvious. It is the specific child.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77093/discussion-between-user9825893y50932-and-vladimir-f).